# kotlin modify dao query based on query results

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am using Kotlin and Room on an Android project. I query for nearby objects on the map based on a bounding box. If too many objects are returned I want to reduce the size of the box. This query is in the a class repository. I want to complete the query in the repository because the result set is stored in view model. The stored value is monitored, and on change, the UI is updated. I want the UI updated only when the query has less than 50 objects
This is the pseudocode in Kotlin for Android.

```
fun getObjectsInRange(smalLat, bigLat, smallLong, bigLong) { 
    val rs = aDao.getObjectsInRange(smallLat, bigLat, smallLong, bigLong)
    return if(rs.size() < 50)
    else getRelicsInRange(smalLat + 0.01, bigLat - 0.01, smallLong + 0.01, bigLong - 0.01)
}
```

This is the query that works, but brings back however many objects in the result set.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM abc WHERE x between :smalLat and :bigLat and y between :smallLong and 
:bigLong")
    fun getAbcInRange(smalLat: Double, bigLat: Double, smallLong: Double, bigLong: Double)
        : LiveData<List<abc>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to refresh the UI when the result set returns less than 50 objects. For this, you can `LIMIT` the result set to 50.

So if the resulted list is 50, that means now you have to reduce the size of the box and if it is less than 50, then you can refresh your UI.

The basic idea here is if you want you to do a change on the basis of a result size, then it doesn't matter how big the size of the list is if it crosses the limit.

Comment: Excellent idea for improving performance. However, I do not know how to check the size of the result, the repository is independent of lifecycle. I don't want to pass a lifecycle owner and I don't want to check the size in fragment. I tried using a list instead of LiveData<List>, but this seems to contradict the Room paradigm. I need to 'peek' at the size of the result set in the repository before sending the set to the calling function. I can not use the 50 limited, they are random and I want the closest objects, that is why I make the bounding box smaller.

Comment: Room supports the ````List```` return type. You can check this on a duplicate query. If the limit size is random you can you ````@RawQuery```` in ````Room````, you can find more about this on https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RawQuery

Comment: The suggestion of @RawQuery is good, but I don't understand how it is better than .allowMainThreadQueries().

Answer (score 0):

This code works, but is HACK. Any ideas for elegance appreciated!!
After looking at @RawQuery, jobs/runBlocking, and cursor I selected
.allowMainThreadQueries() in the getDatabase function then

Code snippet

```
if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        //bla bla
                    )
                        .allowMainThreadQueries() // need for shrinking bounding box
                        .addCallback(object : Callback() {
```

This is snippet in repository...

```
    var xInBox = xDao.getXForBoundingBox(lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2, tooMany)
        while (xInBox.size > maxToDisply) {
            lat1 += 0.01
            lat2 -= 0.01
            lon1 += 0.01
            lon2 -= 0.01
            xInBox = xDao.getXForBoundingBox(lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2, maxToDisply) //List<x>
        }
    return xDao.getXInRangeMaxSize(lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2, maxToDisply) // LiveData<List<x>>
```